# Linked Lists not properly displaying

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a linked list that each node holds a CarPart object. I know that the issue is that I am not properly de-referencing the pointer and it just displays the pointer and not the actual value... problem being is I have not been able to figure out how properly display the car part items to the console.

Per request I have removed any code that does not effect the outcome of what I am trying to do.

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"

int main()
{


    /*cout << new Node(new CarPart("Hello", "World", 99.00));*/

    List partsList;

    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95));
    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("RS12YC", "Spark Plug", 4.15));
    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("D5941", "Digital Tire Guage", 12.15));
    partsList.push_back(new CarPart("G19216", "Car Wash Solution", 8.15));

    partsList.display();
    cout << "now we are going to remove the first item in the list" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    partsList.pop_front();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "now we are going to remove the LAST item from the list" << endl;

    partsList.pop_back();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

List.h

```
#pragma once
#include "node.h"
class List
{

private:
    int listSize;
    Node* n;
    Node* temp;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    List();
    void push_front(CarPart*);
    void push_back(CarPart*);
    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    void display();

    ~List();
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"


List::List()
{
}
void List::display()
{
    Node* test = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        cout << test;
    }
}
```

Node.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CarPart.h"
class Node
{
private:
    CarPart* data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;

public:
    Node();
    CarPart* getData();
    void setData(CarPart*);
    void setNext(Node*);
    void setPrevious(Node*);
    Node* getPrevious();
    Node* getNext();
    void display();
    ~Node();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node()
{
}

void Node::display()
{
    cout << data;
}
```

CarPart.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class CarPart
{

private:
    string partNumber;
    string description;
    double price;
public:
    CarPart();
    CarPart(string, string, double);
    string getPartNumber();
    string getDescription();
    double getPrice();
    void display();
    ~CarPart();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarPart* dt);
};
```

CarPart.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CarPart.h"


CarPart::CarPart()
{
}

CarPart::CarPart(string n, string d, double p)
{
    partNumber = n;
    description = d;
    price = p;
}

string CarPart::getPartNumber()
{
    return partNumber;
}

string CarPart::getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

double CarPart::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarPart* dt)
{
    os << dt->getPartNumber() << endl << dt->getDescription() << endl << dt->getPrice() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: display() should traverse the linked list  and call display() on each node not print the address of the head pointer.

Comment: Did you try to single step the code in a debugger?

Comment: `temp` and `n` should not be members of List.

Comment: I say debugging will not help here. The problem is a lack of implementation.

Comment: I wonder what  `~Node()` does.  Hopefully it's empty and doesn't alter the list.

Comment: data is a pointer. I would expect ~Node would free the memory allocated to data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code, but they all share the same root problem, so I'll just explain the first one, and after figuring out how to fix it you should be able to fix the rest of them by yourself:

```
void List::display()
{
    Node* test = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        cout << test;
    }
}
```

As you've observed, all this does is print the value of the pointer. Examining the contents of your header files, it appears that your class `Node` has a method called `display()`.

You did now show the `display()` method, but given what I see in `List::display()`, it's reasonable to expect that `Node::display`()'s purpose would be similar, so you probably meant to do this, instead:

```
void List::display()
{
    Node* test = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        test->display();
    }
}
```

But this is not right, either. All this will accomplish is invoke your head `Node`'s `display()` method over and over again. If your `List` has five `Node`s, you'll get the contents of the first `Node` `display`()ed five times. You simply need to change this loop to walk through the link list, instead.

Now, your `Node::display`() method has the same problem as above, but now you should be able to fix it yourself.